# How to parse json data and differenciate value required through java script

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I have json Data which has similar variables, i am looking for get the required id value from it. I tried many formats to check/validate the data,but due to same variables available i can't retrieve the required solution.

```
[
  {
    "id": "",
    "email": ,
    "name": "",
    "phone": "",
    "shippingAddress": {
      "address1": "",
      "city": ,
      "country": ,
      "postalCode": ,
      "state": 
    },
    "billingAddress": {
      "address1": "",
      "city": "",
      "country": ,
      "postalCode": ,
      "state": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "",
    "email": ,
    "name": "",
    "phone": "",
    "shippingAddress": {
      "address1": ,
      "city": ,
      "country": ,
      "postalCode": ,
      "state": 
    },
    "billingAddress": {
      "address1": " ",
      "city": "",
      "country": "",
      "postalCode": "",
      "state": ""
    }
  }]
```

I tried similar algorithm's.

```
for (var i=0; i<jsonData.length; i++){
  tests["Checking shippingAddress"] = jsonData.shippingAddress.address == " Constitution ";   
}
```

I am doing Automation in Postman for Api, so api has json data with same variables available.Code is working fine when it has single data.

Comment: So you've got this json or something like this... Can you show us what you expect at the end ? I don't understand "differenciate required values"... ?

Comment: Not at all clear what you are trying to achieve. Broken code is not a good substitute for a proper explanation

Comment: Try `jsonData[i].shippingAddress.address1` instead of `jsonData.shippingAddress.address`

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an issue with how you are iterating through the data.

```
for (var i=0; i < jsonData.length; i++){
  tests["Checking shippingAddress"] = jsonData[i].shippingAddress.address === " Constitution ";   
}
```